# How to design entity tables for entities with multiple names

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I want to create a table structure to store customers and I am facing a challenge: for each customer I can have multiple names, one being the primary one and the others being the alternative names.

The initial take on the tables looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customer (
CustomerId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL --PK
 -- other fields below )


CREATE TABLE dbo.CustomerName (
CustomerNameId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL -- PK
,CustomerId INT -- FK to Customer
,CustomerName VARCHAR(30)
,IsPrimaryName BIT)
```

Though, the name of the customer is part of the Customer entity and I feel that it belongs to the Customer table.
Is there a better design for this situation?

Thank you

Comment: Could a customer have many alternative names, or only 1? If many, then you'll need a second table (especially if "many" is an unquantifiable number), if only one then you could use a single table (with their primary and alternative name as separate columns).

Comment: Rather than using a flag in the `CustomerName` table (which comes with it's own maintenance issues), you could instead store the primary name in the `Customer` table as a FK to the `CustomerName` table.

Comment: Maybe could be better to leave the primary name in `Customer` table. That name is always one, isn't it?

Comment: @Larnu, it can have multiple alternative names.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin, I can leave it in the Customer table, but I have two alternatives: to keep it in CustomerName as well - and in this case I have to maintain it in two places, or to keep it only in Customer - and in this case I need to query both tables if I need to find the list of names for a Customer. Not sure which solution would be the best

Comment: Do you need to store the history of names (e.g. "between 1 Jan 1999 and 2 May 2001, the primary name was "Netscape")?

Comment: How do you know which other names are interesting? How will this be used - is it a "if you can't find customer by primary name, look for alternatives" scenario, or is it "a customer can have many names for different purposes. When you dispatch a product, send to x, when you invoice, send to y"?

Comment: The list of alternative names is not a historical one, it just needs to be there in order to be checked for further activities. Hence the basic use will be to return the primary with the Customer and when needed, to show all the names for one customer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would keep the Primary name in the `Customer` table and create an "AlternateNames" table with a zero-to-many relationship to `Customer`.

This is because presumably most of the time when you are returning customer data, you are only going to be interested in returning the Primary Name.  And probably the main (if not only) reason you want the alternate names is for looking up customers when an alternate name has been supplied.

Comment: thank you! the alternate names are used for some checking activities, but I would need the primary name as well when displaying all the names.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is too long for a comment.

Before figuring this out, more information is needed.

1. Is additional information needed for names?  For instance, language or title or date created?
2. Are the names unique?  Is the uniqueness within a customer or over all names?
3. Are the primary names unique?
4. Does every customer have to have a primary name?
5. How often does the primary name change to an *alternate* name?  (As opposed to just having the name updated.)
6. When querying the data, will you know if the name is a primary or alternate name?  (Or do they all need to be compared?)

Depending on the answer to this question, the appropriate data structure can have some tricky nuances.  For instance, if you have a flag to identify the primary name, it can be tricky to ensure that exactly one row has this value set -- particularly when updating rows.

Note:  If you update the question with the answers, I'll delete this.

Comment: Here are the answers:
1. No, the name is enough
2. Yes, the names are unique
3.Yes
4.Yes, it must have a primary name
5. Not often, but you can have a customer with 3,4 alternate names. If a new name is identified, it must exist in the alternate names. It shouldn't be update anywhere.
6. The primary name will be displayed with the customer. The alternate names will be used in the app by users to check different things, so they need the entire list of possible names for a customer.